# Regular Expression issue pattern matching

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for below string pattern

```
String str = "<name>{f:<one>,l:<two>,t:<three>} )";
```

this pattern ends with "?" so below code works

```
String result = str.replaceAll(pattern, "abc");
System.out.println(result);
```

and the output is

```
<name> ( abc abc)
```

But if the input string changes

where next pattern doesn't end with ?, Java hung.....

```
String result = str.replaceAll(pattern, "abc"); 
System.out.println(result);
```

Equivalent Scala code is

```
pattern.replaceAllIn(str,"abc")
```

Where am I wrong, thanks in advance

Comment: Why use the scala tag? This is Java code.

Comment: I tagged it because it is failing in JVM both in java and scala

Answer (score 0):

From you example it is hard to tell what you try to achieve here are some remarks how the regex could be improved:

There are several strange things in your regex

- `(.)*` could create an infinite number of relatively expensive catching groups if you do not want to use the result later use `(?:)` or at least change to `(.*)`
- `<\\S+?>` is better expressed as `<[^>]+>`

As with most of your matchers you use the non-greedy approach you may run in a bad backtracking issue which could be avoided by changing the regex.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I tried your suggestion, I believe { to be escaped otherwise I am getting "Illegal repetition error". I tried you suggestions but no success. I simplified the input string, can you please try and give me expression which works, Thanks a lot , I appreciate it

Comment: yes you are right `[{]` is valid but only in the parens. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

it should work, if you change your regex to i.e. * at end

```
String pattern = "\\{(((.)*?(<\\S+?>)?)+?)\\}\\?*";
```

or simply

```
String pattern = "\\{.*?(\\})(\\?)*";
```